# Custom post template in a plugin erase theme's one

Tags: wordpress

i work with sportpress on Wordpress. I have a custom plugin that add a lot of function to it.
I created a template for the custom post-type of sportpress. They are in my plugin but i don't find how to make them prioritary on theme. The theme isn't a custom'one, so i don't want to delete or modify anything in it.

I have tried several things but theme's file is everytime superior.
Things tried :

- naming the file 'single-....php',
- filter : `add_filter( 'template_include', 'toornament_template' )`,
- shortcode in theme file (works but not what i want...),

Thanks a lot...

EDIT :

here is what i tried exaclty, it works with another type of post that has no theme template, but not for the one that has single-post template in the theme...

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'player_template', 1 );
function player_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_singular( 'sp_player' ) && file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/player-tpl.php' ) ){
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/player-tpl.php';
    }

    return $template;
};
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be asked over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you're not doing it the right way, you can't just create template file inside your plugin and use them in the admin. Here is a complete tutorial on how to add page template to Wordpress with a plugin : https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/. If you're doing it the right way, don't hesitate to add more information to your question.

Comment: @MathiasNicod Thanks for the answer, i edited my post with what i have actually... In fact, it's like a custom page at all, built from scratch so it can be not a template ?